# Open Source Information about Colleges and Universities

Tags: data-request, collegescorecard, database

I am working on a project building a database of college and university information. I am looking for open-source information that has stats on schools but also general descriptions about the schools. Do you know of any?

Comment: But you have to describe which schools and universities you are looking for?Europe?America?Africa? Asia? or any where please and it does not matter Geography?

Comment: focusing on north america and europe it means you need USA and Canada schools clolleges and in europe may be eastern or western?it depends or its up to you.

Comment: *stats on schools* What stats? Please [edit] that in. Since you use the tag *collegescorecard* you want US data, right? Add another tag.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for data in the US, I would look at [IPED](https://nces.ed.gov/ipeds/).

> The Integrated Postsecondary Education Data System (IPEDS) is the Department of Education’s National Center for Education Statistics’ (NCES) core postsecondary education data collection program. Information is collected annually from all providers of postsecondary education in fundamental areas such as enrollment, program completion and graduation rates, institutional costs, student financial aid, and human resources. **Data collected through IPEDS is publicly released** and can be accessed through the IPEDS Data Center by postsecondary education institutions and the general public.